# Docker Container yarn install ENOMEM: not enough memory

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I'm using docker compose on remote server and in the entrypoint to one of the services I have a shell script that has

```
yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile
```

This had to be done because I'm downloading the project files from git inside entrypoint by adding ssh keys for github from local. The downloading of project files is done only if it's not already available in the volume.

I'm using the user home folder `/home/appuser` as a volume so that it's shared with other services, mounting it like this:

```
    volumes:
      - appuser-home-store:/home/appuser
```

`yarn install` inside this entrypoint has been very unstable, it randomly works but most of the times gives error:

```
error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/workbox-background-sync/-/workbox-background-sync-6.5.4.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "ENOMEM: not enough memory, open '/home/appuser/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-workbox-background-sync-6.5.4-3141afba3cc8aa2ae14c24d0f6811374ba8ff6a9-integrity/node_modules/workbox-background-sync/LICENSE'"
```

Almost everytime the location after `open` is different

In the build I'm using

```
FROM node:lts
```

I have tried
`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192`

But I don't think this is relevant to my problem and didn't work anyway.

I have total of 200GB storage on this server, and I see that only 6% is used. I have tried many things, deleting volume, docker system prune, yarn cache clean and many other but none of them were successful, how to fix this?

Comment: How much RAM is available to the container?

Comment: @Ryker How do I check that? The server has totally 16GB RAM
Just used docker container stats it says around 7.9 GB and 96MB used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a genuine error and known issue even on yarn github:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/4373

The error is not at all same as mine so I could not find it but, one of the solution given on this issue thread worked.

The solution is to set yarn version to canary which can be done using

```bash
yarn set version canary
```